# Convert Project after Android Studio 2.2 update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.2

Hello AndroidStudio Users,

Recently I have updated my Android Studio with **2.2** version, No so many Gradle and Instant Run update I got, that I have updated.

But whenever I open a new project, I am getting the following dialog to convert the project.

Is it required to convert? What it will convert actually? Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: It actually upgrades your gradle version for build. So, for ex. if you have a project with too older version say android studio 1.5 and now you import it in android studio 2.3, It will upgrade your gradle version to 3+ .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just update your build.gradle file for new features of Android Studio.

> buildscript

for Android Studio Version 2.1.3

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

to Latest  Android Studio Version 2.2

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you would find all changes had been made with - the newest version of Android Studio: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22andemulator2522arestable

> This release is focused on bug fixes, performance, and the following
>   new features:
>
> #### Design
>
> - Layout Editor
> - Constraint Layout
> - Layout Inspector (Experimental)
> - PSD File Support in Vector Asset Studio
>
> #### Develop
>
> - Firebase Plugin
> - Updated Code Analysis & Lint checks
> - Enhanced accessibility support
> - Improved C++ Support Edit & Debugging
> - IntelliJ 2016.1.3 platform update
> - Samples Browser
> - Improved Font Rendering
>
> #### Build
>
> - Jack Compiler Improvements
> - Java 8 Language Support
> - C++ ndk-build or CMake
> - Merged Manifest Viewer
> - Build cache (Experimental)
> - OpenJDK Support
> - Instant Run Improvements
>
> #### Test
>
> - Espresso Test Recorder (Beta)
> - APK Analyzer
> - GPU Debugger (Beta)
> - Virtual Sensors in the Android Emulator

Check also: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/09/android-studio-2-2.html

As you see there are many changes which force you to talk with your team mates. If they would decide to stick with older version `2.1.3`, please unnistall the latest one and the most important: don't convert your project, as you may have issues with opening converted project on older Android Studio version.

The problems I alraedy see are:
 - new android sdk version 25.+
 - new Gradle plugin version 
 - constraint-layout

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

changed it just an hour back.. you can convert it !! 
If you are working on VCs tell your team mate to update sdk 25.2.2 . 
Convert the project to new sdk and you gotta feel whole new experience.
 Surprise :xml preview has been changed :)